# WPF cascaded combo

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using LINQ to SQL and MVVM pattern in my application where i am retrieving
my data by the following query:

```
internal ObservableCollection<INVCategory> GetCategoryList()
{
     DataLoadOptions dataLoadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
     dataLoadOptions.LoadWith<INVCategory>(t => t.INVSubCategories);
     this.Context.LoadOptions = dataLoadOptions;

     var categories = from category in this.Context.INVCategories
                      orderby category.CatgeoryId descending
                      select category;
     return new ObservableCollection<INVCategory>(categories.ToList());
}
```

And my XAML code for parent(Category) combo is:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,2,10,2" TabIndex="0" x:Name="categoryComboBox"      
ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList}" IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"  SelectedValuePath="CatgeoryId" SelectedItem="{Binding CategoryList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentEntity.CategoryId, Mode=TwoWay}" >
</ComboBox>
```

for child(Subcategory) combo i am using:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,2,10,2" TabIndex="1"
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=categoryComboBox, Mode=OneWay}" 
DisplayMemberPath="SubCategoryName" SelectedValuePath="SubCategoryId"
SelectedItem="{Binding INVSubCategories, Mode=TwoWay}" >
</ComboBox>
```

But my child combo items is not populated during form loading as well as parent combo's 
selection changed though my parent combo items are populated.
i can't figure out why my child combo is not functioning based on parent combo's
selected item ,please help me.

Comment: It's possible the subcategory combobox's  ItemsSource and SelectedItem bindings are 'fighting' because they're both able to set a value in the combobox. It couldn't hurt to test it with the selecteditem binding removed.
In addition, you could try setting the update trigger field (I don't have the exact property name onhand) for the ItemsSource binding to PropertyChanged.